# How can I write an algorithm to solve this formula for closest point to a set of lines in 3d

Tags: geometry, algorithms

I am trying to understand how I can write an algorithm to solve the formula written at the end of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/61721/64943), that is:

$$ 0=\sum_{i=0}^m \vec c - \vec a_i - \vec d_i \frac {(\vec c-\vec a_i)\cdot\vec d_i}{\|\vec d_i\|^2} $$

I know simple equations systems may be solved through matrices when you have 
$$Ax=b$$ you can solve with $$x = A^{-1}b$$
but this is a little more complicated for me

I think I should come to a form such as:
$$A\vec c = b$$
but I don't have idea how to deal with $\sum$ and dot products

Comment: I agree, but the missing of latex over there suggests this is the best place..

Comment: I was also not sure so I removed my comment.

Comment: Anyway, I gave it a try and wrote also over there, let's see

Comment: Also asked at [StackExchange](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31022828/387778).