# Minimizing $\| x A - B\|_F^2$ With a Constraint

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, matrix-calculus, least-squares, python

I have previously asked an optimization question [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3372945/minimizing-x-a-b-f2). I will reiterate the question and simply add a constraint to it:

I have 2 known grayscale images (256×256 matrices) $A$ and $B$ and want to find the unknown scalar variable $x$ so that:

$$\text{Minimize} \quad \|xA-B\|_F^2$$ 
$$\text{So That All Of The Final Image Values (256x256) Remain Between} \quad 0 \leq xA-B \leq 256 $$

The [previous solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3372973) works just fine but I want to know how to optimize $x$ considering the constraint. Is this considered a Linear Programming problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll get simpler answers if your constraint is that $0\le xA-B\le256$ componentwise.

Comment: @kimchilover Thanks. I edited the question to what you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved as a linearly-constrained linear least squares problem, for which there are many available numerical solvers, accessible from a variety of computer languages and packages. Alternatively, by not squaring the Frobenius norm, it can be solved as a Second Order Cone Problem (SOCP), again for which there are a number of solvers.

Here is how it can be formulated in CVX (under MATLAB), which will transform it to an SOCP, and call a solver to solve it.

```
cvx_begin
variable x
minimize(norm(x*A-B,'fro'))
subject to
0 <= x*A - B <= 256
cvx_end
```

Comment: Thanks for the informed details of your answer. Is there a Python solution available too?

Comment: A similar formulation be be done in CVXPY, under Python; ths syntax is a little different due to Python vs. MATLAB. There are other options as well for Python.