# distance point to affine subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces

I have $n$ points $x_i\in\mathbb{R}^N$, $n \le N$. Is there a general formula for the (squared) distance of another point $b$ to the subspace defined by the $x_i$? (Note that I'm not only looking for hyperplanes; the codimension can be larger than 1.)

Comment: By translation you can assume the point $\overline x$ is the origjn.

Comment: This asks for [minimizing a quadratic form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2606391/minimization-of-a-convex-quadratic-form) if you want to locate the place in the subspace where the distance is minimized.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/173887

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First move $b$ to the origin, $a_i = x_i - b$, and realize that every point in the plane spanned by the $a_i$ can be written as
a linear combination $\sum_i w_i a_i$ with $\sum_i w_i = 1$.
The problem can then be formulated as a least-squares problem with an equality constraint,
$$
\|A w\|_2^2 \to \min,\\
e^T w = 1
$$
with $A\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times n}$ being the column-vector of the $a_i$ and $e=(1,\dots,1)^T \in\mathbb{R}^n$. This can be solved with a Lagrangian approach,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A^T A & e\\
e^T & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
w\\
\lambda
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
If $A^TA$ is invertible, this gives
$$
w = \frac{(A^T A)^{-1}e}{e^T (A^T A)^{-1}e}
$$
and
$$
\min \|A w\|_2^2 = -\lambda = \frac{1}{e^T (A^T A)^{-1}e}.
$$
Note that this expression can never be $0$, so this case is a degeneracy.

---

If not moving $b$ to the origin, the problem is
$$
\|A w - b\|_2^2 \to \min,\\
e^T w = 1
$$
and has the solution
$$
w = \frac{(A^TA)^{-1}e}{e^T(A^TA)^{-1} e} + \left(ee^T - \frac{(A^TA)^{-1}ee^T}{e^T(A^TA)^{-1} e}\right)
(A^TA)^{-1} A^Tb
$$
and the distance
$$
\min \|A w - b\|_2^2 =
\frac{(1 - e^T(A^TA)^{-1} A^T b)^2}{e^T(A^TA)^{-1} e}
 - b^T A (A^TA)^{-1} A^T b
 + b^T b.
$$
(Perhaps this expression can be further simplified.)

---

Compared the @user's answer, this one is faster, particularly for large $N$. (Shown here for $n=3$).

[image]

Code to reproduce the plot:

```
import numpy as np
import perfplot
from scipy.linalg import solve_triangular


np.random.seed(0)

def setup(n):
    # k = 3
    k = n
    A = np.random.rand(n, k)
    b = np.random.rand(n)
    e = np.ones(k)
    return A, b, e


def user(Abe):
    A, b, _ = Abe
    V = (A.T - b).T
    V[:, 1:] = (V[:, 1:].T - V[:, 0]).T
    VTV = V.T @ V
    return VTV[0, 0] - VTV[0, 1:].T @ np.linalg.solve(VTV[1:, 1:], VTV[0, 1:])


def nschloe(Abe):
    A, b, e = Abe
    V = (A.T - b).T
    out = 1 / np.sum(np.linalg.solve(V.T @ V, e))
    return out


def nschloe_qr(Abe):
    A, b, e = Abe
    V = (A.T - b).T
    _, r = np.linalg.qr(V)
    w = solve_triangular(r.T, e, lower=True, check_finite=False)
    w = solve_triangular(r, w, check_finite=False)
    out = 1.0 / np.sum(w)
    return out


def least_squares(Abe):
    A, b, _ = Abe
    b -= A[:, 0]
    A = (A[:, 1:].T - A[:, 0]).T
    _, out, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(A, b, rcond=None)
    return out[0]


perfplot.show(
    # "out.png",
    setup=setup,
    kernels=[user, nschloe, nschloe_qr, least_squares],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(2, 12)],
    xlabel="num points/dim"
)
```

Comment: Looks very nice! Could you give some more details of the formulation of the minimization problem?

Comment: Added some more text; clearer now?

Comment: Yes, thank you! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in a comment we may assume that the point $\tilde{x}$ is the origin of coordinates, the coordinates of the other $k+1$ points being $x_0,x_1,\dots x_{k}$. I will assume that the given $k+1$ points span the subspace of dimension $k$ (otherwise the excessive points are removed until the points are linearly independent).

Introducing the vectors
$$
v_0=x_0,\quad\forall i=1\dots k:\ v_i=x_i-x_0,
$$
an arbitrary point of the subspace defined by $x_i$ can be written as:
$$
r=v_0+a_1v_1+\cdots+a_k v_k
$$
where $a_i$ are arbitrary real numbers.

We are seeking the vector $a=(a_1,\dots,a_k)$ which minimizes:
$$
r^2=(v_0+a_1v_1+\cdots+a_k v_k)^2=a^T Ua+2a^T V+v_0^2,\tag1
$$
where $U$ is symmetric positive definite  matrix with elements $U_{ij}=v_i\cdot v_j$ and $V$ is the vector with elements $V_i=v_0\cdot v_i$. As well known the form (1) is minimized by the vector
$$
a=-U^{-1}V.
$$
Substituting the value into expression (1) one obtains the squared distance to the subspace:
$$
r^2=v_0^2-V^TU^{-1}V.\tag2
$$

Comment: Very nice! I was thinking that maybe one could symmetrize this a little more by writing $r=\sum\alpha_i v_i$, $\sum\alpha_i=1$. This leads to the minimization of $\alpha^T V^TV \alpha$ with $\sum\alpha_i=1$. Looks simple enough, but I'm not sure about its solution.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer I also thought about such possibility (which would boil down to an eigenvalue problem) but it went nowhere. Of course the resulting expression (2) is symmetric in the sense that you can choose any point to be $x_0$ with the same resulting value of the distance.

Comment: Sure thing, it's just that one point is distinguished from the others. It's probably not an eigenvalue (or singular value) problem since we have $\sum\alpha_i=1$, not $\sum\alpha_i^2=1$. Looks like least-squares with equality constraint. Well, perhaps one can average over all $r$s to get a symmetric expression.

Comment: I've added a more symmetric least-squares approach which gives an arguably nicer result.

Comment: @NicoSchlömern Your result looks nice but it does not mean that it is computationally more efficient. I am afraid that the opposite is the case.

Comment: How so? Your $U$ is what I call $A^TA$, so the computational difference is the construction of $V$ in favor of the expression I got.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer No, your matrix is not mine . Mine has dimensions $(n-1)×(n-1) $ and yours - $n×n $, if I don't miss something

Comment: I just tried to compare but I'm struggling to get the correct result from your expression. Here's the gist: https://gist.github.com/nschloe/a901d95bff068e93943d41ba6e4b3a3f

Comment: @NicoSchlömer I have checked both expressions in *Mathematica*. They give the same result (with mine being a bit faster).

Comment: I got it now, but I found my answer is still faster. That's because the benefit of solving a -1 smaller system is outweighted by the vector subtractions ($V - v_0$). Added plot plus code to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Move all points such that the plane of the $x_i$ passes through the origin, e.g.,
$\tilde{x}_i = x_i - x_0$. Every point $y$ in the new plane can be written as
$$
y = \sum_i \alpha_i \tilde{x}_i
$$
with any $\alpha_i$. This leaves us with the least-squares problem
$$
\|b - A\alpha\|^2 \to \min_\alpha
$$
where $A$ is the column-matrix of the $\tilde{x}_i$. This can be solved in multiple ways (SVD, QR, normal equation etc.). One possibility is to create an orthogonal basis in the space, e.g., by (modified) Gram-Schmidt, and project $b - x_0$ onto it.